# Кутафья башня — склонение

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, топонимика

Озадачился таким вот вопросом. Есть в московском Кремле такая *башня Кутафья*.
Как её положено склонять? Как "кто?" ("бегунья","попадья", "свинья") или "чья?" ("девичья", "лисья", "ничья")? ***"Из Кутафьи башни"*** или ***"из Кутафьей башни"***?

Я склоняюсь к первому варианту, хотя справочники дружно за второй. Объясню.

Во-первых, до XIX века притяжательные местоимения на -ий (в женском роде — -ья) имели основным краткий тип склонения, полностью совпадающий со склонением существительных (лисья нора, лисьи норы, лисье норе, лисью нору, лисьей норой, о лисье норе), который не до конца исчез и сейчас. Поэтому основным вариантом должно бы быть именно "Кутафьи" даже в предположении, что кутафья — притяжательное прилагательное на "-ья".

Во-вторых.
Первый вариант предполагает некое имя собственное Кутафья или нарицательное "кутафья". И такое слово действительно фиксируется словарями. Но от него притяжательное прилагательное было бы "кутафиьин" — и такая фамилия тоже существует.

А вот "кутафья" *как притяжательное прилагательное* предполагает наличие некоего или некоей кутафа/кутафы, причем нарицательного, с характерным "человеческим" значением: вдова — вдовья. И это единственный пример, который я могу вспомнить. Варианты "собачья", "волчья" - тут как-то не смотрятся.

Ну и для полноты картины.

По поводу этимологии самого названия нет бесспорных версий. Вот что пишет безусловный авторитет московской топонимистики Михаил Викторович Горбаневский.

> Подходы к ней с северо-запада и к ее Троицкому мосту через реку
>   Неглинную  были защищены Кутафьей башней. Тайна этого названия еще не
>   раскрыта, хотя существует несколько предположений. По одному из них,
>   наименование *башни Кутафья* исторически связывается со словом *кут*
>   «угол». Но это толкование не совсем убедительно, и в основном потому,
>   что объясняет не все слово-название, а лишь первую его половину. В
>   русских народных говорах слово кутафья было довольно употребительно, а
>   в некоторых оно известно и сейчас. В одних (вологодских, псковских,
>   владимирских) — его употребляют по отношению к сильно закутавшейся
>   женщине, в других (олонецких) — этим словом называют неповоротливую
>   или небрежно одетую женщину. Вполне возможно, что Кутафья башня и
>   получила свое название по внешнему виду: не высокая, как все остальные
>   башни Кремля, а приземистая, широкая в основании.

http://moscow.gramota.ru/map503.shtml
*(Курсив — Stack Exchange.)*

К сожалению, из этого отрывка не понятно, как он предлагает склонять само название, поскольку использованные именительный и творительный падежи омонимичны для субстантивного и поссесивного типов склонения прилагательных на "-ья".

Где я ошибаюсь? Есть ли пример подобных образований со склонением по притяжательному типу?

Answer (score 1):

Мне больше нравится другая версия: Кутафья -  не притяжательное прилагательное, а относительное - плечевая.

https://guide-israel.ru/26489-kutafya-bashnya-neuklyuzhaya-baba/

Она действительно похожа на погон - плечо. Если бы это было существительное, то было бы башня Кутафья, а не Кутафья башня, и склоняется она чаще как прилагательное: от Кутафьей башни, к Кутафьей башне,  Кутафью башню, Кутафьей башней, о Кутафьей башне.

По виду, конечно, склонение похоже на притяжательный тип на -ья, но это так усвоилось русским языком - по произношению, по аналогии с русскими прилагательными на -ья.

Comment: _то было бы башня Кутафья_ — любопытно, что в совесткие и досовесткие времена так писали очень часто (Гугл находит таких вариантов больше, кажется). Ещё в нормальных изданиях иногда (редко) попадается написание через дефис: Кутафья-башня.

Comment: Я ознакомился с ссылкой про этимологию обсуждаемого слова. Людмила, Вы согласны, что это так называемая "народная этимология"? Там так и сказано в заголовке страницы. Если согласны, то я решил минусовать любую пропаганду народной этимологии на этой площадке.

Comment: Нет, это не народная этимология (просто на сайте, связанном с туризмом, есть такая рубрика - размышления об этимологии, противоречащие официальной версии), это попытка лингвиста, знатока семитских языков обосновать название с точки зрения связи с семитскими языками, что не назовёшь ненаучным. Эта версия больше вызывает доверие, нежели о кутафье-небрежно одетой женщине. Кстати, рубрика со знаком вопроса: стоит подумать, народная ли это этимология или вполне научная.

Comment: А вот написание через дефис и соотнесение с женщиной как раз похоже на народную этимологию.

Comment: Людмила, ну неужели вы всерьез верите в еврейский след в чисто русском топониме? Впрочем, эта версия ничего не объясняет. Относительных прилагательных на -ья  в русском языке нет, для подобного просто не существует парадигмы склонения. И если уж слово "так усвоилось", то и склонение должно осуществляться в соответствии с правилами для слов с подобными признаками. Ну или вообще не склоняться...

Comment: @grizzly это определенно народная этимология, каковой вообще очень много среди апологетов восточных корней в русском (что татарских, что еврейских, что арабских). Сужу уже по тому, что никаких аргументов за подобную версию (кроме "я так считаю"). Но вы слишком кровожадны. Тут в любом  этимологическом вопросе - 50% народного творчества минимум. Замучаетесь все минусовать. Хуже другое, "версия" не дает ответа на вопрос "а как склонять - и почему".

Comment: *"Глядя на Кутафью башню этим морозным утром, у меня вдруг возник отчетливый человеческий образ:"* - это ж надо такое услышать от человека, претендующего на какие-то лингвистические "открытия". *«Подъезжая к сией станцыи и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа. И. Ярмонкин».*

Comment: Я любитель. А в вопросах этимологии я воспитан на лекциях А. Зализняка. В упомянутой статье я вижу почти все признаки лженауки, по которым советуют определять любительскую этимологию. К сожалению, я не смог найти фамилию этого автора-лингвиста. Я не верю, что этот аноним — специалист по этимологии. Я согласен, что не стоит вот так минусовать всё подряд, но снять свой минус сейчас не могу — он заблокирован до правки ответа. Подниму этот вопрос позже на мете, чтобы посоветоваться.

Comment: А. Зализняк говорил: "Сочинение о языке любительское, если в нём встречается хотя бы одно из следующих утверждений: ... Гласные не имеют значения, существен только «костяк согласных»."
Вот цитата из статьи горе-лингвиста: "...гласные в этимологии не имеют значения, главное — корень — К-Т-Ф." И там всё на таком же уровне, даже хуже.

Comment: @grizzly Да, это отсюда. http://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/430720  Но, тем не менее, я бы вам не советовал тратить силы на минусы тем, кто просто пересказывает мнение подобных авторов. Спорьте с самими авторами, если уж сил не жалко. Ну или когда здесь кто-то сам начинает хулиганить подобным образом от своего имени. Людмила же явно не критически подошла к источнику. Разберется. Что же касается характеристики "лженаука" - это слишком громка сказано. Обычный БСК, не заслуживающий даже внимания. Лженаука в лингвистике - это уровень Чудинова и Фоменки, а тут обычное любительство.

Comment: Собственно, Зализняк так вопрос и ставит. Он разделяет лженауку и "любительскую лингвистику". С первой еще можно как-то спорить, во втором случае это занятие бессмысленное - как от комаров отмахиваться. ЗЫ я тоже любитель, так что не хвастайтесь этим званием.

Comment: @Мимоходов Согласен с Вами, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему убедительных аргументов ни за. Ни против нет.

Все что удалось узнать (со слов знающего человека), это то, что первая словарная фиксация нарицательного слова "кутафья" - середина XIX века.
А єто, дескать, говорит о том, что кутафья исходно - притяжательное. Довод, скажем прямо, слабенький, ведь фиксации порождающего такое прилагательное нарицательного "кутафа" (или подобного) нет вовсе.

Ну и уж совсем не могу серьезно отнестись к версии, что само єто народное нарицательное "Кутафья" произошло от собственного имени башни.
С чего бы это аборигены псковских и вологодских лесов так почувствовали неуклюжесть московской башенки, которую вряд ли многие вообще видели даже на картинке.

Тут мысль-то другая. Претензия на то, что слово "Кутафья" (что бы оно не означало) могла существовать народном языке на большой территории, включая Москву и окрестности. И дать название башне. В московском говоре впоследствии исчезло, но сохранилась именно в диалектах.

В порядке бреда. А может, исходно она "Котафья"? Жена Котофея?