# Падеж субстантивированного прилагательного при числительном два, три четыре

Tags: грамматика

*Предыстория. Один очень умный и весьма авторитетный и заслуженно уважаемый филолог оказал мне честь побеседовать на темы, частично затронутые в вопросах* [Числительные с прилагательным](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/)
*и немного тут.*
[Кутафья башня — склонение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441542)
*В результате я остался совершенно разочарованным, я просто не понимаю смысла некоторых утверждений. Будет несколько вопросов по этому поводу. Чтобы не вводить в искушение предполагаемых участников дискуссии, я вернулся к аккаунту с ником, под которым меня знают.*

Итак. Вот как понял. Предмет для дискуссии - каждый из пунктов и вся логика в целом.

1. Тезис: **У существительных (без всякого исключения) при числительном "два" используется только родительный падеж единственного числа**.

На естественный вопрос, а как быть с субстантивированными прилагательными типа "два прохожих", "два пирожных" или "две столовых", ответа не получил. Насколько я понимаю, чтобы названное утверждение было справедливым, надо либо эти слова вообще исключить из списка "существительных", либо добавить оговорку в сам тезис.

**2. На основании предыдущего тезиса мой собеседник считает, что слово "ничья" не является в полной мере существительным, поскольку родительный падеж там "ничьей".**

Тут мне просто нечего комментировать...

**3. Правильной формой собеседник считает только "две ничьи", нормативное (наряду с предыдущим) "две ничьих" отбрасывается.**

Никаких внятных разъяснений по этому поводу опять же не получил, но зато узнал много "интересного" - см. последующие пункты.

**4. На основании предыдущего мой собеседник прогнозирует дальнейшее изменение и самой нормативной формы родительного падежа слова "ничья": "без ничьи", "никакой ничьи" и прочее.**

Мне кажется подобное ошибочным просто логически. Не может форма при числительном влиять на родительный падеж. Сравните: пять киловатт, но без числительного - "добавить киловаттов в сети", "не знаю я никаких киловаттов!". Здесь немного другой случай, но убедительных примеров такого влияния "двойственной счетной формы" (по Зализняку - одной из двух "счетных форм") на родительный единственного вообще нет. Примеры же иного я приводил.

**4. В качестве примера приводится слово "кабельтов": "два кабельтова**".

Не очень понятно, правда, в каком качестве оно тут вообще выступает, примером чего является. "Кабельтов" вообще не является субстантиватом, с таким же успехом можно было привести "плов" или "альков". 
Хотя слово само по себе интересное, оно относится к смешанному склонению - одном значении. При этом склоняется по-разному в зависимости от значения. Как мера длины - во множественном числе по типу прилагательного, а как название каната, породившего и само "мерное" значение - как существительное, кроме родительного падежа - "моток кабельтовов" и "моток кабельтов". 
Что же касается сочетания "два кабельтова" то наряду с ним используется и два кабельтовых" (какое их них правильно - это надо отдельным вопросом выяснять). В любом случае этот пример кесли что и демонстрирует, то скорее обратный процесс: как слово не являющееся ни в коей мере субстантиватом приобретает парадигму склонения свойственную именно им (в одном единственном хитром случае родительного падежа, правда).

**6. Еще один пример, который автор назвал "убедительным" (не уточнив, правда, в чем именно он убеждает) - русские фамилии на -ов и -ин. "Два Петрова" и "Два Пушкина".**

Тут, на мой скромный взгляд, штука такая. Русские фамилии действительно восходят к притяжательным прилагательным, то есть в роли фамилий такие прилагательные они стали окончательно и бесповоротно существительными-субстантиватами, спору нет.

Но что можно вообще доказать на подобном примере? Что субстантивированное прилагатльное может начать склоняться как существительное? Ну допустим, хотя и с оговорками... Но это единичный случай, других примеров что-то не видно. То есть даже принимая как нормативный совсем не очевидный вариант "два Пушкина" и "два Лермотнова" (будет отдельный вопрос) мы упираемся в очевидную невозможность "два Жуковского", а "Жуковский" уж никак не меньший субстантиват, чем "Лермонтов" или "Пушкин". Да и сам Маяковский вряд ли о себе сказал бы "два Маяковского".

И еще один убийственный (для меня) доводом в пользу формы "два Пушкиных".
"Две Пушкины" не приснится в страшном сне ни одному Маяковскому.

Короче, чем дальше в лес, тем больше деревьев, за которым совсем уже не видно слова "ничья".

Вопрос не о том, чтобы убедить в чем-то моего оппонента, это занятие, видимо, бесперспективное, но если кто-то хоть в чем-то прояснит эту логику, буду весьма признателен. Если я что-то и переврал, прошу извинить, передаю как понял, уточнения принимаются.

Оффспины темы - в связанных вопросах (ссылки - справа).

> Связанные
>   Числительные с прилагательным
>   Кутафья башня — склонение
>   “Первая счетная форма” vs родительный падеж
>   Два Петрова или два Петровых
>   Два кабельтова или два кабельтовых

UPD
Еще одни довод ни о чем.

> Slava1947, у слова "парикмахерская" и слова "ничья" разное склонение.
>   Одно адъективное, другое смешанное.

Во-первых, не смешанное, а местоименное (по Зализняку) 
Во-вторых, для неодущевленных существительных различия только в именительном множественного: "ничьи" и "парикмахерские" (для одушевленных, естественно, еще и в винительном).

> У слов адъективного склонения ваше нет возможности потенциальной
>   принимать какие-то окончание субстантивного склонения, поэтому история
>   совсем другая.

Эмм... А чем же она другая-то? Разве это мешает **сравнивать** одно с другим?
Вы же отвергли сравнение "ничья" и "девичья" именно потому, что они имеют **тождественный** тип склонения. 
Впрочем ладно. Я не понимаю, почу вдруг у слова "ничья" с его типом склонения (как его там ни называй), вдруг появилась столь желаемая вами возможность что-то там "принимать", но в любом случае такая потенциальная возможность не означает, что слово этой возможностью "воспользуется".

Comment: @slava1947 это в первую очередь вам. Вы, вроде, тоже не очень поняли эту логику, может, вместе разберемся.

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/Числительные-с-прилагательным

Answer (score 1):

**У Розенталя:**

https://studfiles.net/preview/985091/page:20/

Субстантивированные прилагательные **мужского и среднего рода** в сочетании с числительными два, три, четыре употребляются в форме родительного падежа множественного числа (ср.: **два дежурных, три насекомых)**, а субстантивированные прилагательные **женского рода** - в форме родительного или именительного-винительного падежа множественного числа (ср.: **две запятых - две запятые** и т.п.).

**Нацкорпус:** чаще используется форма **две/три ничьи**, только один раз встретилась форма **три ничьих**.

**Три ничьих,** и общий «счет ― 2, 5: 1, 5 в пользу команды СССР... [Сало Флор. Кубок остался в Москве // «Огонек». № 40, 1956]

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) Из Грамматики-80:

Числительные ***два, три, четыре*** сочетаются с субстантивированными прилагательными адъективного склонения **только во мн. числе: два морских животных, три насекомых, четыре вторых (блюда).**

2) Из этого можно сделать вывод, что **переход в существительное не дает прилагательному самостоятельности в сочетании с числительными,** что хорошо видно из примера **четыре вторых блюда**. Числительное как бы управляет отсутствующим существительным в ед. числе, а определение стоит в форме множественного числа, как обычно (два больших дерева, две главные задачи).

3) Грамматические прилагательные имеют два типа склонения: **адъективное и смешанное**. Местоимение ***ничей*** относится к **смешанному склонению**, но окончания существительных они имеют только в И.п и В.п. Поэтому можно считать, что правило из Грамматики-80 (о форме мн. числа) относится к этому слову.

Но это ж. род, поэтому возможны две формы: **две ничьих (игры) и две ничьи (игры).**

4) В остальных случаях (не в счетных оборотах) местоимение ***ничья*** имеет полную парадигму смешанного склонения и может употребляться в Р.п. ед. числа.: **никакой ничьей быть не может**.

Пример: Поэтому не стоит удивляться, что главный тренер "Спартака" сумел добиться **ничьей** **(Р.п.)**  в противостоянии сразу с двумя тренерами... "[Алексей Самура. Ничья вслепую.  2002.08.26].

Comment: И что? У Розенталя есть и прямое указание, что обе формы возможны *Как и при выборе формы определения, здесь может сказаться влияние формы сказуемого; ср.: Были зафиксированы две ничьи. – Было зафиксировано две ничьих.*  Но вопрос -то не в этом. И нацкорпус, мы вылизали  во всех направлениях ни один раз... Вы хоть отчасти согласны с тем, что здесь **должен быть родительный единственного**?

Comment: А это как: две ничьей? Нет, я думаю, что должно быть "две ничьих или две ничьи". Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Да именно форма "две ничьей" выступает в качестве некоего аргумента в споре. Но в том-то и дело, что я тем более не могу понять, что именно автор пытается этим сказать. Если вы мне поясните внятно  всю логику... Я могу дать ссылку на открытую часть той "дискуссии", но только как бы "в частном порядке"... Мне хочется, чтобы люди оттуда писали здесь, а не наоборот. ОК?

Comment: Вот полюбуйтесь http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6656 (найдете там - вся тема и конкретно четвертый ответ в теме, а потом и дальше). Там даже прямой вопрос есть "откуда ей" - и непрямой, но прозрачный ответ, что из формы "родительного единственного".

Comment: Я, естественно, не могу здесь выложить всю личную переписку, но если вы дадите канал для связи (мой - в профиле), я не раскрывая инкогнито моего собеседника, перешлю вам извлечения и из неё. Но поверьте, понимания к тому, что есть на том форуме, это добавит.

Comment: Спасибо,  очень интересно. Я просмотрела материалы форума, свои мысли по этой теме попытаюсь изложить во втором ответе

Answer (score 0):

Да,  ***ничья*** –  слово интересное: положение у него особое и фонетика необычная. Всё это способствует развитию его грамматики по **нестандартному** пути.

**Три фактора для этого оказались существенными** (по сравнению с другими субстантивированными прилагательными): местоименное смешанное склонение, женский род, фонетическая форма с суффиксом Й (и связанные с этим трудности произношения).

Всё это видно на следующем примере из форума: **У "Спартака" не было ничьи, а у "Динамо" сразу две ничьи.**  Удобно сказано, наверное, так и будут говорить.

**А переход был простой:** (1) ***две ничьих*** (игры) в общем случае, склонение адъективное  – (2) ***две ничьи*** (игры) склонение адъективное, допускаемый вариант для ж.р. – (3) ***не было ничьи*** (вместо ничьей) – субстантивное склонение для местоименного прилагательного (смешанного склонения), которое полностью и окончательно превратилось в существительное.

Попробуем **сравнить варианты склонения по образцу прилагательного и существительного в разных падежах**:

И.п. У команды одна ***ничья*** и две победы.

Р.п. – У Спартака не было ни одной  ***ничьей/ничьи***.

Д.п. К этой ***ничьей/ничье*** команда добавила убедительный выигрыш.

Т.п. Игра закончилась ***ничьей/ничьёй***, никак не выговоришь, проблемы с обозначением Е/Ё,  лучше – ***вничью***.

П.п. Об этой ***ничьей /ничье***  много говорили.

**И вывод:** переход к варианту склонения по образцу существительного во всех падежах **вполне возможен**.