# Два кабельтова или два кабельтовых

Tags: грамматика

К вопросу [Падеж субстантивированного прилагательного при числительном два, три четыре](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441664)

"Два кабельтова" или "два кабельтовых"?

Чтобы не перегружать ссылками, просто уточню, что в детской литературе (переводной в том числе) советского периода, форма "два кабельтовых" представляется более частотной (но данных очень мало для содержательных выводов). Кто знает, с каким рвением доводились до абсолютной грамотности именно детские издания, должен понять этот аргумент.

Comment: Для справки, единственное число [Ка́бельтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @mmv-ru Я знаю. Только не надо ссылаться на Вики как на источник чего-то там нормирующего.