# Два Петрова или два Петровых

Tags: грамматика

Еще к вопросу [Падеж субстантивированного прилагательного при числительном два, три четыре](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441664) и [Два кабельтова или два кабельтовых](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441666)

Здесь ситуация принципиально отличная от "Два кабельтовых".

С фамилиями в мужском роде более употребительна собирательное "двое": "Двое Пушкиных". Но при этом "два" не является запрещенной (у Розенталя все это есть). Но вот какого падежа (и грамматического числа) требует сама фамилия?

Опять же пример детской литературы советского периода, которую считаю эталоном грамотности.

*Как много школьников у нас!

У нас четыре Аси,

Четыре Васи, пять Марусь

И два Петровых в классе.*
(Барто)

В качестве контраргумента мне привели некие заметки Маяковского где у него "два Пушкина"- и еще всяких разных авторов, хороших писателей и поэтов, но никаких лингвистов.

Есть, правда, некая записная книжка Вяземского, где он говорит о некоем тайном обществе, "где бывали два Пушкин(а/ых)". Но оригинала я не видел, а в цитатах встречается именно "два Пушкиных".

«В конце минувшего столетия, — писал он, — было в Петербурге вовсе не тайное, а дружеское и несколько разгульное общество, под именем „Галера“. Между прочими были в нем два Пушкиных: Алексей Михайлович и Василий Львович…»
http://www.rulit.me/books/vasilij-lvovich-pushkin-read-282780-27.html
Если кто-то утверждает, что видел оригинал Вяземского - буду признателен за ссылку.

Зато вот у выдающегося литературоведа Бориса Эйхенбаума: 
*Дело в том, что для Толстого было два Пушкиных*
("Пушкин и Толстой")
http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/critics/eih/eih-167-.htm?cmd=p
Эйхенбаум Б. Пушкин и Толстой

"Мнение" Вяземского и Эйхенбаума для меня никак не менее убедительно, чем авторский стиль новатора Маяковского.

Короче, мое мнение, что "два Пушкин**а**" это в лучшем случае в библиотеке - два тома Пушкина. Два человека - два Пушкин**ых**.

Жду возражений.

Answer (score 2):

> Если кто-то утверждает, что видел оригинал Вяземского - буду
>   признателен за ссылку.

А скан старого издания подойдёт?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полное собрание сочинений, том VIII, 1883.

А в цитатах в интернете **-а/-ых** примерно через раз.

Comment: Ага!!! Подойдет конечно. Спасибо! Это что же, ваше личное собрание? Или где-то выложено?

Comment: @behemothus Это либген. Но там искать нужно, прямых ссылок нет. И оно не оцифровано (в том смысле, что поиск по тексту не работает). Но по выложенным в сети более современным вариантам можно cориентироваться.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **два Петрова.**

Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#з_06](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_06)

11. В сочетаниях русских фамилий с именами числительными используются такие формы: **два Петрова,** оба Петрова, двое Петровых, оба брата Петровы, два друга Петровы; двое (оба) Жуковских; две (обе) Жуковские. Под это правило подводятся также сочетания числительных с иноязычными фамилиями: оба Шлегеля, два брата Манны.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) С одной сторона форма ***два Пушкина*** встречается в разных источниках, в том числе в XIX веке и в начале XX века (еще до Розенталя):  Пушкин для гоголевского Петрушки совсем не то, что для Гоголя: вот уже ― **два Пушкина**... [Ю. И. Айхенвальд. Вступление к сборнику «Силуэты русских писателей» (1910)].

2) С другой стороны, форма ***два Пушкиных*** тоже имеет право на существование, несмотря на правило.

а) Фамилии с суффиксами ИН и ОВ относятся к **притяжательному** склонению, то есть имеют окончания **не только сущ., но и  и прилаг.** Обратим внимание на Т.п.: с поэтом Пушкиным, но  под городом Пушкином.

б) В счетных оборотах  **адъективное склонение для слов с суффиксами ИН/ОВ во мн.числе** воспринимается на слух как нормативное, например: два **папиных** друга, отсюда ― ***два Пушкиных***.

в) **Лучшим решением было бы разрешить обе формы**, учитывая, что в правиле Розенталя при наличии определений тоже наблюдаются колебания: два Петрова ― два друга Петровы.

Дело в том, что ***два Петровых*** звучит нормально, а вот ***два других Петровых***  уже не очень, лучше сказать ***два других Петрова.***

Comment: Ну да. Фамилия-то и выбрана в качестве примера не случайно. Но это в свете вопроса о родительном падеже одной ссылки на Розенталя явно недостаточно, поскольку формы "два Петровых" и подобные  регулярно появляются. То есть у носителей языка нет явной усановки, что здесь родительный единственного, а не некий счетный падеж. А это ставит под сомнение даже мнение самого Розенталя.

Comment: Я бы допустил в интересах большей инфоромативности варианты "два Петровых" и даже "оба Петровых" - для случая, когда говорится о родственниках, а не просто о подсчитанных однофамильцах. Функцию более явного объединения в группу выполняет числительное "двое".

Comment: О числительном "двое": два мальчика (ед. ч.)  -  двое мальчиков (мн.ч.).